# Telegram API (not Bot!): How to get chat/channel ID by link to it?

Tags: c#, api, telegram

I'm using library [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) on C# and writing Telegram client, and at some moment I got stuck.

I have a link to chat/channel, for instance, https://t.me/joinchat/some-string, and I'd like to get info about the chat/channel or join it. But you can do that only having chat_id, which I don't know how to get.

Firstly I thought about contacts.resolveUsername and passing it "some-string" from the link. But it doesn't work, saying that the username is invalid.

Is there any way to get ID of a group? And was it on purpose to make it so complicated to get info about groups?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Well, I've found the solution (partial, see the end). I'm using [this](https://tjhorner.com/tl-schema/) schema, to let you know.

1. First of all we need to send RPC *messages.checkChatInvite* with parameter *hash* set to last part of your link ("some-string" in my case).
2. A response of type *TLChatInvite* arrives. It will contain primary info about the group: it's type (chat or channel?), participant count and, if you're lucky, they themselves as Vector.

(This point below was the problem of mine)

3. Call the RPC *messages.importChatInvite* with the same parameter hash. It returns *TLUpdates* or *TLUpdatesCombined* object, which will contain a vector of *TLChat* objects. We will need to use the first (don't forget to check the vector for emptiness, though, just in case).

However, *messages.importChatInvite* will make the current user join the group. How to get the ID of the group without getting joined to it I haven't got a clue. Though, this thing would fit for my client.

Frankly said, I'm disappointed it consumed so much time for such a trivial thing.